# How to add text in between the NavigationLink title and the arrow / disclosure indicator - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I add text in between the `NavigationLink` title and the arrow/disclosure indicator as shown in the left image below?

#### SwiftUI Code:

```
struct NavigationStackTest: View {
    let fruits = ["Orange", "Apple"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack{
                List(fruits, id:\.self){ fruit in
                    HStack{
                        //Text("Details")
                        NavigationLink(fruit, value: fruit)
                        Text("Details")
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { item in
                    Text(verbatim: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're just passing a `String` label to the `NavigationLink`. Instead, you can pass a `View` and use an `HStack` and `Spacer` to lay out your content:

```
List(fruits, id:\.self){ fruit in
    NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
        HStack {
            Text(fruit)
            Spacer()
            Text("Details")
        }
    }
}
```